# Correcting shell script vulnerabilities

Tags: security, shell, scripting

What are some simple fixes you would make for the obvious vulnerabilities in this script?

```
#!/bin/tcsh
# foreachfile command
# a shell script to apply command to each file in the current directory

set ListOfFiles = `ls`
set Count = 1
set ListLength = $#ListOfFiles
while ($Count <= $ListLength)
        $argv $ListOfFiles[$Count]
        @ Count = $Count + 1
end
```

Comment: I rolled back your edits because they made the question no make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/tcsh
# foreachfile command <<<< You gave away the ending!
# a shell script to apply command to each file in the current directory

foreach f (*)
        "$argv" "$f"
end
```

You might want to check `$argv` against a whitelist of permitted commands.

Comment: You might also want to insert `--` before `"$f"` if the command understands it.